# Writing a switch that checks $(this) #id as case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, switch-statement

So I have a menu bar which is basically a set of  blocks inside a div. I want to write a jquery script that changes the class of the surrounding 2 blocks in the menu when you hover over a specific one.
I figured I'd do a switch statement that checks $(this) id and then changes the surrounding  class. 
I also want to change the class back once I'm not hovering over again (like it does with the original  I'm hovering over.

adding fiddle for this to make sense

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".kontakt").hover(
       function() {
       $(".kontakt").width("30%");
       $(".kontakt").css("margin-left", "35%");
       
       $(".kontakt").append("<a>mobitel:031-535-919</a>");
       $(".kontakt").append("<br><a>stacionarni tel.:01-3664-515</a><br>");
       $(".kontakt").append("<br><a>email:</a><a href='mailto:sustersic_miha@hotmail.com'>sustersic_miha@hotmail.com</a><br>");
       $(".kontakt").append("<br><a>Visoko 19<br>1292 Ig<br>Slovenija</a>");
       },  
        function() {
       $(".kontakt").empty();
       $(".kontakt").width("10%");
       $(".kontakt").css("margin-left", "45%");
       $(".kontakt").append("<div class='kontaktlabelbox'><div class='kontaktlabel'>Kontakt</div></div>");
        });
    $(".menubutton").hover(
        function() {
        $(this).addClass("activatedmenubutton");
        switch(true){
            case $(this.attr('id') === "iz"):
            $("#1").addClass("activatedmenubutton");
            $("#2").addCLass("activatedmenubutton");
            break
        }
        },
        function (){
        $(this).removeClass("activatedmenubutton");    
        });
});
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    font-family:verdana;
    
    background-image:url("images/background_test.jpg");
    background-size:cover;    
}
.topmenu {
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
    
    background-color:#3366ff;
    
    border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    
    opacity:0.7;
}
.menubutton {
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    font-weight:bolder;
    
    padding:2px;
}
.activatedmenubutton {
    background-color:#cccccc;
}
.menubreak {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    
    padding:2px;
}

.kontaktlabel {
   font-weight:bolder;
}   
.kontaktlabelbox {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin-top:6px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.content{    
}
.kontakt{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:10%;
    margin-left:45%;
    
    background-color:#3366ff;
    
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    text-align:center;
    
    opacity:0.7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Iščem delo</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="unicornsandrainbows.css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="magic.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="topmenu">
            <a class="menubreak" id="1">|</a
            ><a class="menubutton" id="iz">Izobrazba</a
            ><a class="menubreak" id="2">|</a
            ><a class="menubutton" id="zn">Znanja in Kompetence</a
            ><a class="menubreak" id="3">|</a
            ><a class="menubutton" id="izk">Izkušnje</a
            ><a class="menubreak" id="4">|</a
            ><a class="menubutton" id="pč">Prosti Čas</a
            ><a class="menubreak" id="5">|</a
            ><a class="menubutton" id="fo">Fotografije</a
            ><a class="menubreak" id="6">|</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">            
        </div>
            <div class="kontakt">
                <div class="kontaktlabelbox">
                    <div class="kontaktlabel">Kontakt</div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

so basically I want #1 and #2 to lit up when I hover over #iz, #2 and #3 to lit up when I hover over #zn" and so on...I also want them back to their original class after I'm not hovering over the button anymore.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You don't even need a switch.

```
$(".menubutton").hover( function() {
    $(".topmenu a").removeClass("activatedmenubutton");
    $(this).addClass("activatedmenubutton");
    $(this).prev().addClass("activatedmenubutton");
    $(this).next().addClass("activatedmenubutton");

});
```

Comment: This works perfectly for what I needed. For some reasons it doesn't work with adding/removing classes, but works for single properties, got it with `code     $(".menubutton").hover(
        function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#cccccc");
    $(this).prev().css("background-color", "#cccccc");
    $(this).next().css("background-color", "#cccccc");
},
function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
    $(this).prev().css("background-color", "#ffffff");
    $(this).next().css("background-color", "#ffffff");    
});`
seems strange to write every property in jquery though

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
case $(this.attr('id') === "iz"):
```

... to ...

```
case ($(this).attr('id') === "iz"):
```

... missing bracket.

Comment: this solved it, the `code $("#1").addClass("activatedmenubutton");` part doesn't work, but at least I got it to console.log a string so I know the case is written properly.

Answer (score 0):

The key of the switch statement should be the property of the element, and each case should be a potential value. Your current code, aside from the syntax error, is effectively using an `if` statement. Try this:

```
switch (this.id) {
    case "iz":
        $("#1, #2").addClass("activatedmenubutton");
        break;
}
```

It should be noted though that a `switch` with a single case is redundant and you may as well use an `if` statement.

Comment: I have 5 cases but didn't write all 5 since the first one didn't work :). Thanks though, at least I learned the proper switch syntax